# undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/posts/5/like":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a small social web app and users should be able to like other user's posts. Here is my link_to for 'liking' a post.

```
<%= link_to "like", like_post_path(post), method: :post do %>
```

---

And here is the error message I get:

**undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/posts/5/like":String**

Originally this said `posts/6/like`, but I deleted that post in console and now it says 5.

I am new to rails and I have no idea what this means. If you need any more code, let me know. I am trying to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the block way for `link_to`, the first value is the path, and you put the value in the block, everything else comes after the path is considered as a hash, and rails calls `stringify_keys` on it. In your case, you put 'like' as the first argument, which rails considered as the path, and `like_post_path(post)` is simply a string without a pair. henceforth the error

Either

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :post do %>
  like
<% end %>
```

Or just use the one liner, without the `do`

```
<%= link_to "like", like_post_path(post), method: :post %>
```